# Sql query to display employee details based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with following schema:

A)

```
--------------
Employee
-------------- 
EmpID  EmpName 
1      Abc
```

B)

```
Address 
-----------------------------------
AddressId EmpID  Address1 Status
-----------------------------------
1         1      Abc 1    Active
2         1      Abc 2    Inactive
```

I want to display  employee  details like EmpName, Address1 based on following scenario:

- a) If Employee has an active and inactive address, the query will display the 
  active address.
- b) If Employee has only an inactive address, the query will display the inactive 
  address.
- c) If Employee has multiple active or inactive addresses, the query will display the first address in the database prioritizing the active address.

Below is my Sql query

```
SELECT a.EmpID, a.status,   Count(a.Status) as Count,      
CASE  
 WHEN Count(a.Status) = 1 and a.Status In ('Active', 'Inactive') 
 THEN (select top 1 a.Address1 from Address a where a.Status = 'Active')

 WHEN a.Status= 'Inactive' and count(a.Status) = 1
 THEN (select top 1 a.Address1 from Address a where a.Status = 'Inactive')

 WHEN Count(a.Status) > 1 and a.Status In ('Active', 'Inactive') 
 THEN (select top 1 a.Address1  from Address a where a.Status = 'Active') 
END AS Address1 
from Address a where  Attendee_Id= 1 group by a.Status, Address1, a.EmpId
```

Comment: I smell homework.  Have you tried something yourself yet?

Comment: when you supply the schema, the actual create table will be useful as it also shows the column types. and indeed, this does look like a C&P from a homework question:  Address1, Status 1 1 Abc 1 Active 2 1 Abc 2 Inactive??

Comment: adding a dbfiddle may help: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: @pradeep: consider higlightng your code by surrounding it with a bachtick. If absent on your keyboard you can add it with alt+96 (on numpad) or adding it to the original question

Comment: select top 1 ... from address order by id,status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select e.*, a.*
from employee e outer apply
     (select top 1 a.*
      from address a
      where a.empId = e.empId
      order by status,  -- "Active" is before "Inactive"
               addressId
     ) a;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

row_number approach

```
select * from 
(
select *  
     , count(*)     over (partition by e.EmpID) as cnt 
     , row_number() over (partition by e.EmpID 
                          order by a.Status, a.AddressId) as rn
from employee e
join address a
  on a.EmpID = e.EmpID 
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```